# how could I access users profile using settings parameter in drupal behaviours?

Tags: users, javascript

I have a behavior as follows:

```
Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
  attach: function(context, settings){
    jQuery("#edit-user-address",context).change(function(){
      console.log(" user id and other fields "+settings.user.id);


    });
  }
}
```

How could it be achieved?

Comment: What about passing the variables you need by using drupal_add_js (settings) in your custom module?

Comment: how would drupal_add_js(settings) interact with my behavior?

Comment: See the examples on Drupal's API. [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)

Comment: Yes, that is what I wanted, please compile your suggestions into an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Drupal's `drupal_add_js` function with the 'settings' option ([more info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7)).

**Example:**

```
global $user;
$uid = $user->uid;
drupal_add_js(array('myModule' => array('uid' => $uid)), 'setting');
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if you try to display `hostname`. The hostname will be cached per-user so all anonymous users will share the same IP.